# How properly configure url rewriting in htaccess with a custom webroot with CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Here is my folder structure (it's a shared hosting) :

```
ROOT: /htdocs
APP_DIR: app
WEBROOT_DIR: www
WWW_ROOT: /htdocs/public/www/
CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH: /htdocs/lib
```

CakePHP runs but not url rewriting as I have left the original .htaccess files untouched.
I get an internal server error as soon as I click a link.

How should I modify the default .htaccess so that url rewriting works?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this documentation page will help: [CakePHP URL Rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess)

Pay attention to `RewriteBase` directive.

Answer (score 0):

So far, it seems that only the .htaccess in the webroot (htdocs/public/www/.htaccess) needs to be modified.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```